# POST data not sent using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS 1.9 (Windows). When I send a POST XMLHttpRequest to my server with PhantomJS like this

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://my_server_url", true);
xhr.send("TEST");
```

The request itself arrives correctly at the server, but the POST data (here: "TEST") is not there.

Executing the exact same script from a browser console (i.e. Chrome) works fine! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like it should work. When you send the actual data, is it just a string like that? or is it json or something? I prefer using the FormData() object to send POST requests.

Comment: @OtotheA: Yes, it is cross-domain!

Comment: here is an example i posted in another question. It is a GET request, but should get you started [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535058/including-cookies-on-a-ajax-request-for-cross-domain-request-using-pure-javascri/22816079#22816079). There are some access-control headers you must have set up on the server side as well.

Comment: @OtotheA: Yes, it is a string.

Comment: @OtotheA: I don't think that CORS is the problem here, because that problem is solved by sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from the server. Nevertheless all initial request data should be sent, despite CORS. As I said: It works from the browser.

Comment: how are you accessing the data on the server? I guess i'm not sure because I typically send post data as a key value pair using the FormData() object and the .append() method. Can you post a screenshot of the request and response headers/data?

Comment: @OtotheA: How would you do a "screenshot" with PhantomJS? Are you aware that my problem occurs with Phantom?

Comment: Sorry, i guess i assumed phantom was a framework or something. There's no dev console with network activity logs of some kind?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with 2.1.7

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that the PhantomJS async POST request was made in the context of a Jasmine test in Karma. I didn't make the Jasmine test async (I didn't use the `done` callback), so the test ended before the data was transferred asynchronously. To fix this, use the `done` callback in your `onreadystatechange` handler for the XHR request.